# Associate packaged_task and thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, packaged-task

all

I have a class:

```
class someClass
{
 public:
    vector<int> someOperation(int start, int end)
    {
         // do something...
    }
}
```

and a main function:

```
int main()
{
    someClass obj;

    std::packaged_task<vector<int>(int, int)> task(&someClass::someOperation);

    std::thread t1 = std::thread(std::move(task), &obj, 0, 200);   // Error happens here
    std::thread t2 = std::thread(std::move(task), &obj, 201, 400);
    std::thread t3 = std::thread(std::move(task), &obj, 401, 600);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    return 0;
}
```

**I expect this code can create three threads that run same operation on different part of a piece of data.** However, in the definition of thread t1, compiler pops following error:

```
error C2046: term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments
```

May I know what am I wrong, and how can I do it right?

Many thanks in advance.

Long

Comment: Not really the problem here, but what do you think `std::move(task)` does? Since it gets moved into the first thread, the `task` won't be valid afterward for creating the next threads.

Comment: Might be me not understanding the sense of `packaged_task`, but why don't you use some `std::future`s directly?

Comment: @ArneMertz where do you get the futures from? You can *never* just use futures directly. You need some source for them. `packaged_task` is a source of futures that produce results from the execution of a function.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes of course, silly me. Meant `std::async`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `&someClass::someOperation` cannot be used without an instance of `someClass`. You realise that because you do pass one such instance into the thread constructor, *but forgot it* in the `packaged_task` signature:

```
std::packaged_task<vector<int>(someClass*, int, int)> task(&someClass::someOperation);
```

Another issue is that you are trying to move `task` into three different places. That won't work: after it moves once, the `task` won't be valid anymore, and moving it into the other threads won't do what you expect. You need three different tasks.